# Share instance across different VM using compose and Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'd like to share the same instance of an object across two viewModels. This instance must be destroyed when ViewModel1 is cleared.

I'd like NOT to use @SingletonComponent or @ActivityRetainedComponent due to the rest of the app architecture.

```html
@SomeScope
data Class1(...)

@HiltViewModel
class ViewModel1(instance1: Class1) @Inject constructor() : ViewModel()

@HiltViewModel
class ViewModel2(instance1: Class1) @Inject constructor() : ViewModel()

@Composable
fun MyNavigationHost(navController: NavHostController) {

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = VIEW_MODEL_SCREEN) {
        composable(VIEW_MODEL_SCREEN_1) {
            val viewModel1 = hiltViewModel<ViewModel1>()
            ScreenWithSubScreen(content = ViewModelScreen(viewModel1) , subScreen = SomeOtherScreen(...)) 
        }
        ....
    }
}

@Composable
fun SomeOtherScreen(.....) {

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ViewModel1Route) {
        composable(VIEW_MODEL_2_SCREEN) {
            val viewModel2 = hiltViewModel<ViewModel2>()
            SubScreen(viewModel2)
        }

    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is way to do this though Hilt but I can't figure out exactly do do it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To provide the same instance of a non-singleton object in Android Hilt in a specific case, you can use the `@Named` annotation. This annotation allows you to give the object a unique name, which Hilt will then use to identify it.
For example, the following code will create a new instance of the `Foo` class each time it is injected, except for the case where it is injected with the name "myFoo". In that case, Hilt will return the same instance of the `Foo` class that was created the first time it was injected with that name.

Note that this can only be used with non-singleton objects. If you try to use it with a singleton object, Hilt will throw an error.

```
@Provides
@Named("myFoo")
fun provideFoo(): Foo {
  return Foo()
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohsen, yes I thought about passing down the viewModel. I've added more details in the question to explain a bit more the context around it. 

In a nutshell, I can't really do this as  AnotherScreen will not know about what instances are contained in MainViewModel (except if I add some extra interfaces in MainViewModel which is what I'd like to avoid)

Comment: Hi. I did'nt get what you exactly want to do. But if the problem is about your bottom sheets, yoy don't have to create them as separate screens, you can add ModalBottomSheetLayout to the screen that you want to open bottom sheet there and pass the same viewModel instance to it.
I hope I'm not misundestood of your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your patience. I've edited the question for more clarity.